# ./gradlew assembleRelease produce very old Apk

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to generate a new apk and I get a very old apk when I run
`./gradlew assembleRelease`
I am using react native above 0.63.
I tried to remove the build folder and remove caches and it still produces the old apk.
**so my question is why does it produce the old apk? and how to get the new apk?**

Comment: Try ./gradlew clean then ./gradlew assembleRelease

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  cd android
 ./gradlew clean 
 ./gradlew assembleRelease
 cd ..
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete files inside directory `android/app/src/main/assets`.
2. run `$react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`
3. `$ react-native run-android`

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
rm -rf android/app/build
rm -rf android/build
cd android
./gradlew clean
cd ..
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
cd android
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

this should clean the build folder and create a new `index.android.bundle` with all the updates